# Prism & MEF Project Setup

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I am trying to configure an wpf project using prism and mef.
I have a problem and I don't know how to resolve it. The uncommented code do not execute but the commented code works. 
Do you have any ideea?

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Shell.xaml
/// </summary>
[Export]
public partial class Shell : Window, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    private const string ModuleName = "FirstRegion";
    private static Uri ViewUri = new Uri("/UserControl1", UriKind.Relative);

    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
    public IModuleManager ModuleManager;

    [Import(AllowRecomposition = false)]
    public IRegionManager RegionManager;

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        this.ModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted +=
                           (s, e) =>
                           { 
                           ---------(do not execute)-----------
                               if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == EmailModuleName)
                               {
                                   this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(
                                       "MainContentRegion",
                                       ViewUri);
                               }
                           };


        //this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(
        //    "MainContentRegion",
        //    ViewUri);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems LoadModuleCompleted event was fired before the call of OnImportSatisfied().

Can you try moving code in constructor to confirm above assumption

```
public Shell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted +=
             (s, e) =>
                           { 
                           ---------(do not execute)-----------
                               if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == EmailModuleName)
                               {
                                   this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(
                                       "MainContentRegion",
                                       InboxViewUri);
                               }
                           };
}
```

Comment: Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.